# Window 10 network diagnosis erase my static IP config, can I find it back?

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-adapter

There is some issure with my network, and I click the "diagnosis" button, then I lost my static IP config! Is there a backup file or log file to find it back?

Comment: Your router may have a log of your previous connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the registry key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`. Under it should be a list of GUIDs, each of them contains information about an IP configuration you had on your computer. They also contain info whether that IP address was given to your computer by a DHCP (`DHCPEnabled`), so that field should be 0x0 in the record you're looking for.